# Simulating an Android Camera

Tags: android, video, camera, android-camera

I am testing imaging algorithms using a android phone's camera as input, and need a way to consistently test the algorithms. Ideally I want to take a pre-recorded video feed and have the phone 'pretend' that the video feed is a live video from the camera.

My ideal solution would be where the app running the algorithms has no knowledge that the video is pre-recorded. I do not want to load the video file directly into the app, but rather read it in as sensor data if at all possible.

Is this approach possible? If so, any pointers in the right direction would be extremely helpful, as Google searches have failed me so far

Thanks!

Edit: To clarify, my understanding is that the Camera class uses a camera service to read video from the hardware. Rather than do something application-side, I would like to create a custom camera service that reads from a video file instead of the hardware. Is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing processing on a live android video feed you will need to build your own [custom camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) application that feeds you individual frames via the [`PreviewCallback` interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html#onPreviewFrame%28byte%5B%5D,%20android.hardware.Camera%29) that Android provides.

Now, simulating this would be a little bit tricky seen as the format for the preview frames will generally be in the NV21 format. If you are using a pre-recorded video, I don't think there is any clear way of reading frames one by one unless you try the [`getFrameAtTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long,%20int%29) method which will give you bitmaps in an entirely different format.

This leads me to suggest that you could probably test with these Bitmaps (though I'm really not sure what you are trying to do here) from the `getFrameAtTime` method. In order for this code to then work on a live camera preview, you would need to have to convert your NV21 frames from the `PreviewCallback` interface into the same format as the Bitmaps from `getFrameAtTime`, or you could then adapt your algorithm to process NV21 format frames. NV21 is a pretty neat format, presenting color and luminance data separately, but it can be tricky to use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That's a good solution but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. My understanding is that the Camera class relies on a camera service that communicates with the hardware. Rather than edit the camera class I want to create a custom camera service that reads from a video file rather than the hardware. I'll edit above for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Creating a custom camera class as I suggested does not entail editing the camera class–it simply means that you are able to handle the camera yourself and get preview information, the alternative being creating a simple intent to get images or video captured from the device's native camera app. Are you saying that you don't want to work from a live preview ever? And you looking for a way to use the traditional camera but provide a video as input as opposed to the hardware? If so, this is not possible... why would you want to use the camera for this anyway?